# Prisma, NextJs, Issue with nested query with nested where Provided Json, expected Int

Tags: json, next.js, nested, where-clause, prisma

This is my first post issue of all my life. I love programming, you're inspiration for me... so, let's begin:

My schema is huge, so i will try to explain:
· 1 guide has many components
· 1 components has many tags
· 1 tag has many aspects
· 1 aspect has many items

but also:
· 1 guide_approvement has fk aspect_id, fk item_id, fk guide_id, fk department_id
· the aspects and the items must recieve a rating

this is the thing: i´m doing pretty well the query but i can´t add many filters, i need select rating active = true AND department_id = userDepartmentId and others, but i just can do well the where id: guide?.id at the beggining

Reading the documentation i tried to do nested where with: where: { table: { is: { field: value ... but i recieve this error "Provided Json, expected Int."

In the following lines you will see errors, it's in purpose, that's i want to approach:

```
let data = {
table: "guide",
action: "get", // findUnique
body: {
where: { // not work
id: {
is: {
id: valueGuide?.id,
},
},
},
select: {
id: true,
date: true,
version: true,
component_guide: {
select: {
component: true,
},
orderBy: {
id: "asc",
},
},
tag_guide: {
select: {
tag: true,
},
orderBy: {
id: "asc",
},
},
aspect_guide: {
select: {
aspect: true,
},
orderBy: {
id: "asc",
},
},
item_guide: {
select: {
item: true,
},
orderBy: {
id: "asc",
},
},
guide_approvement: {
select: {
comment: true,
aspect_guide_id: true,
item_guide_id: true,
rating: {
select: {
value: true,
where: { // not work
is: {
active: true,
},
},
},
},
},
where: { // not work
departament_id: user.departament.id,
},
},
},
},
};
```

prisma.table.findUnique(url, data)

Hope your help, thanks a lot

i try to do nested where with prisma and nextjs, i expect help! thanks.